# What is preferred char type for cross-platform C++ exceptions and base logging facilities?

Tags: c++, utf-8, api-design, wstring

### Preamble:

I've been programming primarily on Windows for the past 20 years. During that time, I've developed extensive string conversion, logging, and exception reporting mechanisms that rely on Windows API for utf-16le string conversion facilities and underlying I/O services to capture runtime exception context for debugging, logging, reporting, etc.

I had to simply make the choice when we went to Windows utf-16le native code a while back to change most of those fundamental services to express them all in wchar_t fundamentals (or std::wstring which is utf-16le on Windows).  I say "had to" because it all hangs together quite well - one achieves a high degree of agreement between the WinAPI itself, and file I/O and console I/O, they all can be made to work well in utf-16le.

Windows provides narrow string I/O and current code page support - but that never works as well as keeping everything in utf-16le, which is then portable across various systems and remains coherent - nothing "lost in transcription."

### Goals:

I'm looking to generalize my libraries, but I'm flummoxed by this fundamental disconnect between what was easy(er) under Windows: using `wstring` for all of the logging and exception data which guarantees that my trace captures and errors which contain locale-specific strings (e.g. locale-specific filenames or user-named elements) remain in their native strings and do not suffer degradation when loaded on my English system -- vs. Linux systems which seem to prefer utf-8 as their core string encoding which is often more compact - but which is very hard to make work for a Windows based application (this is a complex topic - but suffice it to say that Windows doesn't adequately support utf-8 for console I/O or any other file I/O and you're going to have to convert constantly to utf-16le anyway for WinAPI calls - which for a GUI based app, is absolutely constantly - so it's just easier to settle on utf-16le as your 'standard' string type and build up from there).

However, I'd love to have a great programmer-friendly set of exception classes that capture context in a way that is equally "natural" and convenient to the c++ programmer on Unix as well as on Windows.

So this creates some difficult to answer questions - especially since my knowledge of programming c++ on Linux is lacking:

### Questions:

1. Do I provide base exception classes that always capture utf-16le on Windows, but utf-8 on Unix?
2. How do I convert between APIs which allow for either string type (well, technically, I'd like to provide for std::string and std::wstring - which may be utf-16le or utf-32 on Windows vs. Linux).

### Further Considerations:

For #2, I see that the c++ 11 standards body created `std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>>` but deprecated it for c++17.

I could of course rely on Windows APIs when compiling for that platform, but I really want something as fundamental as an exception class hierarchy - whose whole purpose is to make capturing runtime error context easy for the programmer - to have to rely on native services.  I really want that core part of my library to only rely upon C++ std library services - I'd prefer to avoid C runtime library services for that matter (note: I don't mind if the std lib relies on C runtime under the hood - that's irrelevant to my concerns, and would be a platform-specific issue, not a dependency created by my library).

So, I'm curious as to what other C++ professionals who have more experience with Linux and Mac OS based systems think would dovetail most easily between their own convenience of writing out an exception and being able to easily capture and manipulate trace and log files or other diagnostic I/O?

Correction: C++11 introduced the converter, and C++17 deprecated it.

Comment: Mandatory: [UTF-8 Everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/)

Comment: Thanks.  It always seemed like UTF-8 was just a better system - especially given that UTF-16 is endian-variable, and it isn't fixed width.  That still leaves the necessity of converting filenames and urls and all other windows native strings to utf-8 in a c++ std way - which seems to be nonexistent.

Comment: Do you really have to use a `std` method?  ICU is a portable C++ library that will handle all of the conversions for you.

Comment: In my workplace we've settled on using [QString](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) as our cross-platform solution to this problem.

Comment: "UTF-16 ... isn't fixed width" -- UTF-8 isn't, either.

Comment: I'm really wanting to avoid any other library dependencies here.  This is intended to be the core exception hierarchy for the core portion of the library with zero external dependencies except c++14 or better.

Comment: Do you need also translation? Check what translation libraries prefer.

Comment: "*That still leaves the necessity of converting filenames and urls and all other windows native strings to utf-8 in a c++ std way - which seems to be nonexistent.*" - there are Win32 APIs for that (`WideCharToMultiByte()` and `MultiByteToWideChar()`), C++ APIs (`std::wstring_convert()`, etc), 3rd party libraries (libiconv, icu, etc), and so on. Plenty of ways to handle this